# How do I know if a replacement screen is dead on arrival?

Tags: hardware, broken-screen

I dropped and broke my One Plus One's screen and subsequently replaced the screen/digitizer. However, there is a vertical strip on the screen where touch is not sensed properly. Before I replaced the screen, the areas where touch did not work was completely different on the original broken screen. What would be a way for me determine if this is an issue with my dis-assembly/assembly or if the replacement screen I got was already broken (dead on arrival)?

The replacement screen was [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00V9UBOSW).

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Comment: I just posted what I did in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the screen by plugging it in after disassembling my one plus one but not using any of the adhesives yet.